# Modify an object in a nested list created by ggplot and ggpubr?

Tags: r, ggplot2, nested-lists, ggpubr

Consider the following MWE, where the heights of imaginary teenage participants are measured in an imaginary study:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Create data for height, measured at two time points, for imaginary participants
participant_id <- 1:100
`Time point 1` <- rnorm(100, mean = 162, sd = 7)
`Time point 2` <- rnorm(100, mean = 165, sd = 7)
heights <- tibble(participant_id, `Time point 1`, `Time point 2`)

# View the head of the data
head(heights, n=3)
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   participant_id `Time point 1` `Time point 2`
#>            <int>          <dbl>          <dbl>
#> 1              1           165.           176.
#> 2              2           168.           175.
#> 3              3           176.           173.

# Stack the data to long format for ggplot
heights_long <- stack(heights[,c(2, 3)])

# View the head and tail of the data
rbind(head(heights_long, n=2), tail(heights_long, n=2))
#>       values          ind
#> 1   164.6773 Time point 1
#> 2   167.7354 Time point 1
#> 199 159.0590 Time point 2
#> 200 158.5412 Time point 2

# Create a ggplot object
bp <- ggplot(heights_long, aes(x=ind, y=values, fill=ind)) +
  ggtitle("Height measured at two time points") +
  geom_boxplot() +                                 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +                
  labs(x = "Time point of measurement") +          
  labs(y = "Height (cm)")

# Add mean comparison p-values with stat_compare_means
p1 <- bp + stat_compare_means(
  method = "t.test",
  label = "p.format",
  show.legend = FALSE,
  paired = TRUE,
  comparisons = list(c("Time point 1", "Time point 2")),
  method.args = list(symbol = TRUE)
)

# Display the ready graph
p1
```

[image]

```r
  
# Introduce a custom function for rounding a p-value
custom_round <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x >= 0 && x < 0.01 ~ "p <.01",
    TRUE ~ paste0("p = ", format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2))
  )
}
```

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Now the question: what if I wanted to stylize the p-value (here: 0.041) that is displayed in the graph with the above custom function `custom_round`?

Can I access that "field" direct in the object "p1", or do I have to first put it through ggplot_built, then try to apply the function and perhaps only then try and display the modified new graph object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to find the instructions myself from [elsewhere](https://github.com/kassambara/ggpubr/issues/65#issuecomment-395137940) on how to directly access the data in the ggplot object.

The solution can be seen below. This gives the user full control on what to display and is more powerful, IMHO, than the "built-in" symnum_args argument of `stat_compare_means()`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Create data for height, measured at two time points, for imaginary participants
participant_id <- 1:100
set.seed(123)
`Time point 1` <- rnorm(100, mean = 162, sd = 7)
`Time point 2` <- rnorm(100, mean = 165, sd = 7)
heights <- tibble(participant_id, `Time point 1`, `Time point 2`)

# Stack the data to long format for ggplot
heights_long <- stack(heights[,c(2, 3)])

# Create a ggplot object
bp <- ggplot(heights_long, aes(x=ind, y=values, fill=ind)) +
  ggtitle("Height measured at two time points") +
  geom_boxplot() +                                 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +                
  labs(x = "Time point of measurement") +          
  labs(y = "Height (cm)")

# Add mean comparison p-values with stat_compare_means
p1 <- bp + stat_compare_means(
  method = "t.test",
  label = "p.format",
  show.legend = FALSE,
  paired = TRUE,
  comparisons = list(c("Time point 1", "Time point 2")),
  method.args = list(symbol = TRUE)
)

# Display the ready graph
p1
```

[image]

```r
# Introduce a custom function for rounding a p-value
custom_round <- function(x) {
  case_when(
    x >= 0 & x < 0.01 ~ "p < .01",
    TRUE ~ paste0("p = ", format(round(x, 2), nsmall = 2))
  )
}

## Extract data with ggplot_build
p1build <- ggplot_build(p1)

## Explore data in p1build to find the right variable (here the command is commented)
#p1build$data

# In this case, the p-value could very easily be found in: p4build$data[[2]]$annotation

# Turn p-value "back" to numeric, then apply the function
p_rounded <- p1build$data[[2]]$annotation %>% as.numeric() %>% custom_round()

# Replace the original p-value with the rounded p-value
p1build$data[[2]]$annotation <- p_rounded

# Plot anew
plot(ggplot_gtable(p1build))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

I think what you're looking for can be achieved with the `symnum.args` argument of `stat_compare_means`.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)

# Create data for height, measured at two time points, for imaginary participants
set.seed(200)
participant_id <- 1:100
`Time point 1` <- rnorm(100, mean = 162, sd = 7)
`Time point 2` <- rnorm(100, mean = 165, sd = 7)
heights <- tibble(participant_id, `Time point 1`, `Time point 2`)

# Stack the data to long format for ggplot
heights_long <- stack(heights[,c(2, 3)])

# Create a ggplot object
bp <- ggplot(heights_long, aes(x=ind, y=values, fill=ind)) +
  ggtitle("Height measured at two time points") +
  geom_boxplot() +                                 
  theme(legend.position = "none") +                
  labs(x = "Time point of measurement") +          
  labs(y = "Height (cm)")


# Set symnum argument
symnum_args <- list(cutpoints = c(0, 0.0001, 0.001, 0.01, 0.05, Inf), symbols = c("p <= 0.0001", "p <= 0.001","p <= .01", "p <= .05", "ns"))

# Add mean comparison p-values with stat_compare_means
p1 <- bp + stat_compare_means(
  method = "t.test",
  label = "p.format",
  show.legend = FALSE,
  paired = TRUE,
  comparisons = list(c("Time point 1", "Time point 2")),
  method.args = list(symbol = TRUE)#,
  #symnum.args = symnum_args
)

p2 <- bp + stat_compare_means(
  method = "t.test",
  label = "p.format",
  show.legend = FALSE,
  paired = TRUE,
  comparisons = list(c("Time point 1", "Time point 2")),
  method.args = list(symbol = TRUE),
  symnum.args = symnum_args
)

# Display the ready graph
p1
```

[image]

```r
p2
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2023-04-27 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks, I think I will likely use the approach you described! However, I think it doesn't give an ultimate control over how the statistic is rounded/visualized, compared to the approach that I am after. Do you happen to know how the statistic can be directly extracted from the ggplot object - and put back to it? (If not, I will accept your answer anyways. I might create another "ticket" for the original question in some other context to see, if anyone knows an answer.)